# Topology: basis and subbasis

Tags: general-topology

please, can you give me a hint?

1.- The topology generated by a basis is unique.

2.- Every basis is a subbasis.

3.- Let $T_B$ be the topology generated by the basis $B$. Let  $K$ be such that $T_B$ properly contains $K$ and $K \nsubseteq B$. Is $B \cup K$ a basis? If $B \cup K$ is a basis, let $T_{B \cup K}$ be the topolgy generated por $B \cup K$, are the topolgies $T_B$ and $T_{B \cup K}$ be comparable?

Sorry for my English, but I am a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is not a question. It is a set of four questions

Comment: Moreover, you didn't include any attempts.

Comment: hint. 1 review the definitions and use them, 2. try to decide whether it is true and if so prove it: (a) $T_{B \cup K}\subseteq T_B$ and/or (b) $T_B\subseteq T_{B \cup K}$